# How do I create a new col3 in a dataframe that checks for multiple values if they are in col1 and also check for values in col2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Existing Dataframe and Desired Result either Pandas or NumPy:
contactid, bonustype, bonusreceived, NEW_COLUMN

```
contactid     bonustype     bonusreceived      NEW_COLUMN
100           a             yes                ab
100           b             no                 NULL
200           a             no                 NULL             
200           b             yes                abc
200           c             yes                abc
```

I have to check from bonustype if both values (a,b) are true and bonusreceived is 'yes' for contactid then return (ab) in NEW_COLUMN.
If all three bonustype (a, b, c) and bonusreceived is 'yes' then return (abc) in NEW_COLUMN.

I have tried several tricks but not able to get the above desired result. Any help will highly be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The result is explained but the logic not.

Comment: Does it matter if `bonusreceived' is true for all of the bonustype values or just at-least-one-of the bonustype values?

Comment: What should be in the new column if no bonuses have been received?

Comment: Please check the value of `NEW_COLUMN`.  Should be `a` for 100 and `bc` for 200, right ?  For 100, only `a` is `yes`.  For 200, only `b` and `c` are `yes`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the clarified requirement that

1. for every `contactid`, each `bonustype` should be used only once in the aggregated text in `NEW_COLUMN`
2. for `bonusreceived` == 'no', the corresponding `NEW_COLUMN` should be `NULL`

We can use [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`transform()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html) and join the unique text of `bonustype`.  Then, use [`np.where()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to ensure only when `bonusreceived` == 'yes' we get the aggregated text and set `NaN` otherwise.

```
import numpy as np

df['NEW_COLUMN'] = np.where(df['bonusreceived'] == 'yes', 
                            df.groupby('contactid')['bonustype'].transform(lambda x: ''.join(x.unique())),
                            np.nan)
```

**Data Input**

```
print(df)

   contactid bonustype bonusreceived
0        100         a           yes
1        100         b            no
2        200         a            no
3        200         b           yes
4        200         c           yes
5        100         a            no
6        200         a           yes
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

   contactid bonustype bonusreceived NEW_COLUMN
0        100         a           yes         ab
1        100         b            no        NaN
2        200         a            no        NaN
3        200         b           yes        abc
4        200         c           yes        abc
5        100         a            no        NaN
6        200         a           yes        abc
```

Comment: Hi @SeaBean - Thank you for the response and solution it is mostly working but it still has 2 issues that I am facing
1) 
   contactid bonustype bonusreceived NEW_COLUMN
0        100         a           yes          aa
1        100         b            no          a
2        200         a            no         bc
3        200         b           yes         bc
4        200         c           yes         bc
**5      100          a           no        aa**     
**5      200          a           no        aa**

Comment: contactid bonustype bonusreceived NEW_COLUMN
0        100         a           yes          aa
1        100         b            no          a
2        200         a            no         bc
3        200         b           yes         bc
4        200         c           yes         bc
**5      100          a           no        aa**     
**5      200          a           no        aa**

Comment: so anytime I have additional record it appends bonustype letter to it. 
I am using the below script to eliminate repeating letters.
min_threshold_rep = 2
column_name = 'Name'
dataframe[column_name]= dataframe[column_name].str.replace(r'(\w)\1{%d,}'%(min_threshold_rep-1), r'\1')

2) Even though the bonusreceived is no it is applying the same logic to it....when the bonusreceived is 'no' then the field NULL(because it doesn't meet the condition)

Comment: @user17066146  See my edit above.  Edited solution for your clarified requirements.

Comment: @SeanBean thank you for your help and I just clicked the check mark on the right.